# Getting button names to string format

Tags: objective-c

I have a lot of custom buttons in my program and I need to use methods to get their names. I've figured out how to get their names through their tag, but I cant seem to follow it through to have the name in a string format.

Heres what I'm using:

```
-(void)pickRandomToHide {
    for (int check = 1; check <=5; check++)
    {
        int eventNumber = 1 + arc4random() % 43;
        UIButton *pick;
        pick = (UIButton *)[_mapImageView viewWithTag:eventNumber];
        [pick setHidden:YES];
        NSString *buttonName;
        buttonName = [pick currentTitle];
        NSLog(@"%@",buttonName);
    }
}
```

The NSLog just gives 'Null' five times. But 5 buttons are disappearing so the start is working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any titles is because the buttons are hidden and disabled, whereas the titles are likely only set to appear when the button's control state is "normal" (enabled and visible). [Here's more information from Apple on the UIButton control states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

Try doing this:

```
-(void)pickRandomToHide {
    for (int check = 1; check <=5; check++)
    {
        int eventNumber = 1 + arc4random() % 43;
        UIButton *pick = (UIButton *)[_mapImageView viewWithTag:eventNumber];
        if(pick)
        {
            [pick setHidden:YES];
            NSString *buttonName = [pick titleForState: UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"%@",buttonName);
        } else {
            NSLog( @"hmmm, no button with a tag corresponding to event number %d", eventNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the [pick setHidden:YES] just to show that the first part works, it isn't the actual program so that's not the problem. I tried your code and it didn't work either anyway.